# Cross-platform offline/online app/webapp: Service Workers / AppCache?

Tags: offline, service-worker, html5-appcache

I have to build a webapp/Android/iOS application which works both online and offline (when the internet coverage is bad). The application should download/sync data and HTML pages when it is online.

I am planning to use Angular 2, but am still confused about the technologies to use for the offline part. Service Workers seem great, but they are not supported by iOS. iOS supports AppCache, but this is deprecated in the [Web standards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache).

Is there a cross-platform technology that supports offline for Web, iOS and Android?

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?